# Loop through a list of series to create dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, time-series, nested-lists

I have a list of dates, where each date has a series of codes. I also have a dataframe containing multiple columns, one col with codes unique for a product and others with product characteristics. I need a new dictionary or similar that can hold that extra time dimension, i.e. for each date I need the product code and the characteristics. I want to loop over the list of dates and match by unique product codes and then add all the codes that matches and product info to each date.
This is how I made the list of dates with series of codes

```
list_of_dates_with_codes = rw_data[rw_data['Dates'].isin(reb_dates)].groupby(
    'Dates')['codes'].agg(set)
```

This is a simplified sample of my dataframe

```
stdata = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['H1', 'gum', 1], ['H4', 'wheel', 299], ['H7', 'table', 99]]), columns=['code', 'product name', 'price'])
```

If I wanted it with one date only, I could do it like this, however I need the time dimension, so any suggestions to how I can extend my code to add that extra dimension in a dictionary?

```
fl_st_data = stdata[stdata['code'].isin(list_of_dates_with_codes)]
```

Any help is appreciated

I hope it makes sense. Feel free to ask for any other relevant info

Comment: Please include a sample of your DataFrame, as well as your expected output. For example, the output of `rw_data.head().to_dict()`

Comment: I have added my dataframe (simplified).

Comment: The dates are the first business day in each month as string type

Comment: I dont know how to illustrate my expected output. Each date I have match with product codes. I want that product code and associated product data in a dict.